# Django Dynamic Dropdown Menu Not Populating

Tags: jquery, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on a project where the task is to implement a dynamic drop-down menu where the choices in the menu will change depending on the value that the user selects from a previous drop-down menu.

I have the first dropdown menu populated with the values of the `name` keys in the JSON below (`Network 1`, `Network 2`, etc.).  My goal is that the second dropdown will populate with a list of the `zone` values that correspond with the `name` value that the user selects in the first dropdown.

So, if the user selects `Network 1` from the first dropdown, the second dropdown will populate with `network.1.private.zone` as its only option.  If the user selects `Network 2` from the first dropdown, then the second dropdown will populate with `network.2.private.zone` as its only option, and so on.

Thanks in part to this [guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html), I've made quite a bit of progress on this.  I can see the AJAX request firing in the browser, and the `url` and `networkId` values seem to be correct when I `console.log` them to the browser.  But I can't figure out why the dynamic dropdown menu isn't populating.  Here is a screenshot of what the page looks like:

[image: Django project page with dropdowns and browser console showing.]

Notably, my project does not have any models; rather, all the data I'm working with is stored in the JSON file, referenced above and seen below.  What am I missing?

Pertinent code included below:

Here is the JSON file:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Network 1",
    "onboard": {
      "format": "network",
      "base": "172.27.22.0",
      "mask": "255.255.255.0",
      "zones": ["network.1.onboard.zone"]
    },
    "private": {
      "format": "network",
      "base": "172.24.16.0",
      "mask": "255.255.252.0",
      "zones": ["network.1.private.zone"]
  },
    "public": {
      "format": "network",
      "base": "128.237.78.0",
      "mask": "255.255.255.0",
      "zones": ["network.1.public.zone"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Network 2",
    "onboard": {
      "format": "network",
      "base": "172.27.23.0",
      "mask": "255.255.255.0",
      "zones": ["network.2.onboard.zone"]
    },
    "private": {
      "format": "network",
      "base": "172.24.234.0",
      "mask": "255.255.254.0",
      "zones": ["network.2.private.zone"]
    },
    "public": {
      "format": "network",
      "base": "172.24.234.0",
      "mask": "255.255.254.0",
      "zones": ["network.2.public.zone"]
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

**utils.py (The JSON file above is referenced here as WIRED_GROUPS)**

```
...
def return_zones_by_network(network_name, network_group=WIRED_GROUPS, private=True):
    """
    Helper function that will eventually be used to construct the dynamic dropdown menu.
    **** WIRED_GROUPS is the JSON file referenced earlier in this post ****
    """
    network_zones = []
    for network in network_group:
        if network['name'] == network_name:
            if private:
                for zone in network['private']['zones']:
                    network_zones.append(zone)
            else:
                for zone in network['public']['zones']:
                    network_zones.append(zone)
    return network_zones
...
```

**forms.py**

```py
class WiredRegistrationForm(Form):
    
    def __init__(self, groups, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['group'].choices = ((0, '---------',),)
        self.fields['group'].choices += tuple(
            (i+1, groups[i],) for i in range(len(groups))
        )
        self.fields['hostname_zones'].queryset = ((0, '---------',),)

    network = ChoiceField(
        # choices=wired_network_choices,
        choices=wired_network_choices,
        widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )

    hostname = CharField(
        label='Hostname',
        max_length=63,
        error_messages={'incomplete': 'Enter a hostname.'},
        validators=[HOSTNAME_VALIDATOR],
        widget=TextInput(attrs={
            'autocomplete': 'off',
            'autocapitalize': 'off'
        })
    )
    # this is the field that needs to be dynamically populated.
    hostname_zones = ChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )

    mac_address = MACAddressField(label="MAC address")

    group = ChoiceField(
        widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )
```

**views.py**

```py
def load_hostname_zones(request):
    """
    A view to return a list of hostname zones for a given network.
    """
    # somehow get the network name that the user selected
    network_name = request.GET.get('network')
    network_zones = return_zones_by_network(
        network_name=network_name
    )
    return render(request, 'hosts/register/host_zones_dropdown_list_options.html', {'network_zones': network_zones})


def register(request):
    """
    The REGISTER view.
    """
    if is_requestor_wireless(request):
        return redirect('hosts:register_wireless')
    return redirect('hosts:register_dorm')


def register_wired(request):
    """
    The REGISTER WIRED view.
    """
    user = get_remote_user_from_request(request)

    if len(get_hosts_for_user(CONN, user)) >= MAX_REGISTRATIONS:
        msg = (
            'You can\'t register any more devices because you have too many '
            'currently registered to your Andrew ID. If you still need '
            'additional devices registered, please contact the '
            '<a href="https://www.cmu.edu/computing/support/" target="_blank">'
            'Help Desk</a> for assistance.'
        )
        return register_failure(request, msg)

    
    zone = ZONES['wired']['private']
    network_list = []
    for network in WIRED_GROUPS:
        network_list.append(network['name'])

    context = {
        'network_list': network_list,  # the list above
        'max_devices': MAX_REGISTRATIONS  # 100
        'zone': zone
    }

    groups = get_member_from_request(request)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        context['form'] = WiredRegistrationForm(groups)
        return render(request, 'hosts/register/wired.html', context)

    form = WiredRegistrationForm(groups, request.POST)
    context['form'] = form

    # checks if the form passes all the validation rules
    if form.is_valid():
        # access the user-input data (pretty sure the data will be a dict)
        # process the data... THESE ARE REFERENCED IN THE HTML TEMPLATE AS "form.hostname", "form.mac_address", etc.
        data = form.cleaned_data
        hostname = data['hostname']
        mac_address = data['mac_address']
        network_id = int(data['network'])
        # this code block references the datacubes library
        networks = Network.search(
            CONN,
            network=WIRED_GROUPS[network_id]['private']['cidr']
        )
        network = networks[0]
        zone = network['private']['zones']
        fqdn = f'{hostname}.{zone}'
        addr = network.next_available_ip()[0]
        ipv4addr = HostIpv4addr(CONN, {
            'ipv4addr': addr,
            'configure_for_dhcp': True,
            'mac': mac_address,
        })
        choice = form.cleaned_data['group']
        extattrs = {'suspend': 0}

        if int(choice) > 0:
            extattrs['group'] = groups[int(choice)-1]
        else:
            extattrs['andrewid'] = get_remote_user_from_request(request)
        try:
            host = Host.create(
                CONN, fqdn, ipv4addrs=[ipv4addr], extattrs=extattrs
            )
        except HTTPError:
            msg = (
                'A device with the same hostname or MAC address has '
                'already been registered.'
            )
            return register_failure(request, msg)
        grid(CONN).restartservices()
        return redirect('hosts:register_success', ref=host.objref)

    # renders the request to the hosts/register/WIRED page.
    return render(request, 'hosts/register/wired.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'hosts'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(
        r'^register/$',
        views.register,
        name='register'
    ),
    url(
        r'^register/wired',
        views.register_wired,
        name='register_wired'
    ),
    url(
        r'^register/wired/load-hostname-zones',
        views.load_hostname_zones,
        name='register_wired_load_hostname_zones'
    ),
    ...
]
```

**/templates/hosts/register/wired.html**

```html
{% extends 'hosts/register/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block css %}
{{ block.super }}
<link href="{% static 'fonts/fontawesome/css/solid.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'fonts/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/group-hide.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock css %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
{{ block.super }}
<span>Register Device</span>
<span> &#160;&#8250;&#160;</span>
<span>Wired Network</span>
{% endblock breadcrumbs %}

{% block content %}
<div class="boxes">
  <h1>Register Device - Wired Network</h1>
  <p>
    Students, faculty, and staff can complete this form to register a computer or device in a campus building. Up to {{ max_devices }}
    devices can be registered. Devices are registered with a <em>private IP</em> address, which provides additional
    security when accessing Internet resources. Contact the Help Center to request a public IP address for a device.
  </p>
  <p>
    <em>Note</em>: To register a device located in academic or administrative buildings not supported by this application as well as departmental
    computers/devices in residence halls, visit
    <a href="https://www.cmu.edu/computing/services/endpoint/network-access/wired/how-to/index.html" target="_blank">
      How to Connect to the Wired Network
    </a>.
  </p>
  <div>
    <form method="post" id="wiredRegistrationForm" action="{% url 'hosts:register_wired' %}" data-zones-url="{% url 'hosts:register_load_hostname_zones' %}" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
{#    <form method="post" id="registerWiredForm" action="{% url 'hosts:register_wired' %}" hostname-zones-url="{% url 'hosts:load_hostname_zones' %}">{% csrf_token %}#}
{#    <form method="post" id="registerWiredForm" hostname-zones-url="{% url 'ajax_load_hostname_zones' %}">{% csrf_token %}#}

      <fieldset>
        {# network field #}
        <div>
          {{ form.network.label_tag }}
          {{ form.network }}
        </div>
        {# hostname field #}
        <div class="">
          {{ form.hostname.errors }}
          {{ form.hostname.label_tag }}
          <div>
            {{ form.hostname }}
{#            .{{ form.zone }}#}
            . {{ form.hostname_zones }}
            <p>
              A hostname is a nickname used to identify a device connected to the network. It can be comprised of any
              string of alphanumeric characters without spaces.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {# mac address field #}
        <div>
          {{ form.mac_address.errors }}
          {{ form.mac_address.label_tag }}
          <div>{{ form.mac_address }}</div>
          <p>
            A MAC address is a unique identifier assigned to a Network Interface Card (NIC) by the manufacturer. Visit
            <a href="https://www.cmu.edu/computing/services/endpoint/network-access/wireless/how-to/mac-address.html"
               target="_blank">Find My MAC Address</a> for help.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" class="groupCheckbox"/>
          <label>Register this device for a group or department.</label>
          <div class="groupSelector">
            <p>Group: {{ form.group }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
{#        <div>#}
{#          {{ form.network.label_tag }}#}
{#          {{ form.network }}#}
{#        </div>#}
        <div>
          <div>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fas fa-undo fa"></i> Reset</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-id-card fa"></i> Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $("#id_network").change(function () {
          let url = $("#wiredRegistrationForm").attr('data-zones-url'); // get the URL of the "load_hostname_zones" view
          console.log(url);
          let networkId = $(this).val(); // get the selected hostname ID from the HTML input
          console.log(networkId); // this works (prints out 1, 2, 3, 4, etc., depending on what network you select)
            $.ajax({
              url: url,
              data: {
                'network': networkId // add the network id to the GET parameters (is this right???)
              },
              success: function (data) { // "data" is the return of the "load_hostname_zones" function
                $("#id_hostname_zones").html(data); // "data" is defined above...
              }
            });
        });
      </script>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block js %}
{{ block.super }}
<script src="{% static 'js/mac-address.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock js %}
```

**/templates/hosts/register/host_zones_dropdown_list_options.html**

```html
{# This is only used to compose the tiny bit of HTML that is the hostname zone dropdown menu #}
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for hostname_zone in hostname_zones %}
{#<option value="{{ network_zones.index(network_zone) }}">{{ network_zone }}</option>#}
  <option value="{{ hostname_zone.pk }}">{{ hostname_zone.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out.  The issue was a discrepancy between my helper function in the **utils.py** file, seen here:

```py
def return_zones_by_network(network_name, network_group=WIRED_GROUPS, private=True):
    """
    Helper function that will eventually be used to construct the dynamic dropdown menu.
    **** WIRED_GROUPS is the JSON file referenced earlier in this post ****
    """
    network_zones = []
    for network in network_group:
        if network['name'] == network_name:
            if private:
                for zone in network['private']['zones']:
                    network_zones.append(zone)
            else:
                for zone in network['public']['zones']:
                    network_zones.append(zone)
    return network_zones  # returns a list, not a dict
```

and the tiny template in **/templates/hosts/register/host_zones_dropdown_list_options.html**, seen here:

```py
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for hostname_zone in hostname_zones %}
  <option value="{{ hostname_zone.pk }}">{{ hostname_zone.name }}</option>  # this line here
{% endfor %}
```

In the template, I was referencing properties of each `hostname_zone` (**pk** and **name**) when in reality each `hostname_zone` is a string from a list.  I guess I'm a bit surprised that I wasn't getting something like an attribute error by referencing non-existent properties, but the dropdown menu is dynamically populating as it should now.

The corrected template is below.  Hopefully this helps someone else down the road:

```py
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for hostname_zone in hostname_zones %}
  <option value="">{{ hostname_zone }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```